# Rails Websocket disconnect after connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, websocket, postman

I have a Rails server that can accept websocket connections. The problem is that when I connect to the websocket I get disconnected directly with error code 1006 (from Postman). In my local development environment the connection works. Interesting to know is that if I authenticate incorrectly I get a reasonable message but as soon as I use the correct token to authenticate the connection is terminated.

**postman log with wrong token**

```
Disconnected from ws://smarthome.this-co.de/cable?token=6f891434-74d2-4b4b-ac06-9974500e206 11:19:45 
1000 Normal Closure:

Connection was closed successfully.
{"type":"disconnect","reason":"unauthorized","reconnect":false} 11:19:45

Connected to ws://smarthome.this-co.de/cable?token=6f891434-74d2-4b4b-ac06-9974500e206 11:19:45
```

**Postman log with correct token**

```
Disconnected from ws://smarthome.this-co.de/cable?token=6f891434-74d2-4b4b-ac06-9974500e2064  11:21:45
1006 Abnormal Closure: No close frame was received.

{"type":"welcome"}  11:21:45

Connected to ws://smarthome.this-co.de/cable?token=6f891434-74d2-4b4b-ac06-9974500e2064  11:21:45
```

**channel/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
   class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
      identified_by :current_system

      def connect
        self.current_system = find_current_system
        reject_unauthorized_connection unless current_system
      end

   private

     def find_current_system
       ApiToken.find_by(api_token: request.params[:token])&.system
     end
  end
end
```

**Nginx conf**

```
upstream puma_smarthome {
server unix:///home/rails/apps/smarthome/shared/tmp/sockets/smarthome-puma.sock;
}

server {
  server_name smarthome.this-co.de www.smarthome.this-co.de;

  root /home/rails/apps/smarthome/current/public;
  access_log /home/rails/apps/smarthome/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/rails/apps/smarthome/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
 }

 try_files $uri @puma_smarthome;

 location @puma_smarthome {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://puma_smarthome;
 }

location /cable {
   #proxy_pass http://89.58.12.188:80;
   proxy_pass http://puma_smarthome;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   #proxy_redirect off;
   #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

#if ($Scheme = http) {
 #     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
#}
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
 client_max_body_size 100M;
 keepalive_timeout 10;
 listen 80;
 listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/smarthome.this-co.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by  Certbot
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/smarthome.this-co.de/privkey.pem; # managed     by Certbot
 include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Production log**

```
I, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.915760 #1337668]  INFO -- : [0d184e95-cae8-4102-92e0-41c6de5d0b2c] Started GET "/cable?token=[FILTERED]" for 77.20.211.45 at  2023-08-19 11:21:45 +0200
I, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.916342 #1337668]  INFO -- : [0d184e95-cae8-4102-92e0-41c6de5d0b2c] Started GET "/cable?token=[FILTERED]" [WebSocket] for 77.20.211.45 at 2023-08-19 11:21:45 +0200
I, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.916396 #1337668]  INFO -- : [0d184e95-cae8-4102-92e0-41c6de5d0b2c] Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
D, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.916984 #1337668] DEBUG -- : find_current_system!
D, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.918154 #1337668] DEBUG -- :   ApiToken Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "api_tokens".* FROM "api_tokens" WHERE "api_tokens"."api_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["api_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.929561 #1337668] DEBUG -- :   System Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "systems".* FROM "systems" WHERE "systems"."api_token_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["api_token_id", "[FILTERED]"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.934377 #1337668] DEBUG -- : in der connect methode
I, [2023-08-19T11:21:45.934729 #1337668]  INFO -- : Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vc21hcnRob21lL1N5c3RlbS83)
```

**channel/espsystemchannel.rb**

```
class EspSystemChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    Rails.logger.debug 'subscriberd method!'
    stream_from "esp_system_channel_#{current_system.id}"
  end

  def receive(data)
    Rails.logger.debug "receive methode!"
    json_data = JSON.parse(data)
    # Verarbeite die empfangenen Daten und sende eine Antwort an den ESP8266
    response = "Response from Rails: #{json_data['message']}"
    transmit(response: response)
    #ActionCable.server.broadcast('esp_test_channel', response: response)
  end


  def unsubscribed
    Rails.logger.debug "unsubscribed methode!"
    #last_call({test: "testi"})
    stop_all_streams
    # Aktionen, die beim Trennen der Verbindung ausgeführt werden sollen
  end


  def last_call(hash)
    Rails.logger.debug "last call methode!"
    puts hash
    puts Time.now
  end
end
```

If you need more info let me know

Comment: Consider that the Ruby WebSocket is running a custom `ActionCable` protocol on top of the WebSocket protocol - this means that any WebSocket message that violates the `ActionCable` protocol should result in immediate disconnection... Does your Postman message follow the `ActionCable` protocol?